# Sencha Architect 3 - in my model how do I set mappings in the Fields

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, sencha-architect

Sencha Architect 3, in my model, how do I set mappings in the Fields (Ext.data.Model) so that I can extract data from my nested JSON??

There seems to be no way I can see to do this within Architect.

It seems my only way around this is to edit the .js outside of Architect which I do not want to do in case I screw up the metadata files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, there **is** the `mapping` config option for fields in Architect 3. See the screenshot.

[image: Mapping of model fields in Sencha Architect 3]

Comment: Thank You Saki for the screenshot, found it, I feel a bit silly, I was not seeing it earlier.